# How to run set of classes in TestNG without disturbing their order?

Tags: java, testng

Lets assume I have three packages and each package has 3 classes. And in turn each class has 3 @test methods with priority ranging from 1 to 3.

I want to run one class file from each package. When I do with  tags, the priority=1 are all executed first. **I want the run the tests, class by class, say all 3 test methods of class1 execute first and then class2 methods are picked up**. How can we achieve this?

My current order which runs all priority=1 test methods of all classes first..

```
<test name="ClassTest" group-by-instances="true">

    <packages>
        <package name="com.presetup" />
        <package name="com.javahelper" />
    </packages>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.package1.class1" />
        <class name="com.package2.class2" /> 
        <class name="com.package3.class3" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

**Update:**
*Workaround I found:*

Is having different test tag for each class, hence each class will run one after the other

```
    <test name="1" group-by-instances="true">

    <packages>
        <package name="com.required" />

        <classes>
            <class name="com.package1.class1" />
        </classes>
        >
    </packages>
</test>

<test name="2">

    <packages>
        <package name="com.required" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.package2.class2" />
        </classes>
        >
    </packages>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `preserve-order="true"` attribute to your `<test>` tag and try again. That should basically help you preserve the order of the tests as you specify.

> I want to run one class file from each package

This as far as I know, is **NOT** possible with TestNG. You cannot have testng toggle between multiple packages at a given point in time, pick a class from a package and run them. For doing that, you would need to resort to using the TestNG APIs wherein you instantiate a `TestNG` object and through code, you would need to read all classes in a package, and then write code which would do this for you. There's nothing available for satisfying this ask out of the box.